# Why jsp returns null?

Tags: java, jsp

I have this code in one jsp and i want to sent to the another and display selected value and correct answer. In the first page i have this code:

```
<form method="post" action="result.jsp" >

                    <p>choose answer</p>
                    <select name="fill">
                        <option value="0">Fill</option> 
                        <option value="1">England</option> 
                        <option value="2">China</option> 
                        <option value="3">France</option> 

                        </select>
                      <input type="submit" name="sent" />
                     </form>
```

and then the second jsp:

```
 <body>
        <jsp:declaration>
        String s = "";
        </jsp:declaration>   

        <jsp:scriptlet>
           s = request.getParameter("fill");
        </jsp:scriptlet>
        <h1>Your answer is <jsp:expression>s </jsp:expression>and correct is England</h1>


    </body>
```

And it returns null, why?

Comment: is request object defined ? (is request not null for.sure ?? )

Comment: Works fine for me on Glassfish 4.0.